# Is there support for ordinal number suffixes localization?

Tags: python, django

For example if I have n-th apple (1st apple, 2nd apple, 3rd apple), how will this be translated in django?
Is there some function to get suffix for given n?
Looks like this depends on the gender of the word:

```
1re pomme, 2e pomme
1r homme 2e homme
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would generally use [gettext's pluralisation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/translation/#pluralization) feature for this kind of thing:

```
ngettext('%(num)dre pomme', '%(num)de pomme', n) % {'num': n}
```

In this case of course you're not really interested in the *localisation* of the string and only in the *pluralisation*, so this isn't very different from:

```
'1re pomme' if n == 1 else f'{n}e pomme'
```

In fact, if the rules are more complicated than that (which I don't know for French, but for English you'd have 4 different cases), then `ngettext` becomes a bit of a kludge. You *can* create PO files which look like this:

```
msgid "%(num)dst potato"
msgid_plural "%(num)dth potato"
msgstr[0] "%(num)dre pomme"
msgstr[1] "%(num)de pomme"
msgstr[2] "%(num)d... pomme"
```

That would require a proper setup of the `nplurals` option of the PO file and it can consider any number of grammatical rules here. See section 2.4 Plural Forms of [this excellent guide](http://pology.nedohodnik.net/doc/user/en_US/ch-poformat.html) for a deep dive.

However, again, gettext is primarily for *translation*, and this would be somewhat kludgy.

If "pomme" itself is a variable, e.g. `vegetable_name = 'pomme'; print(f'{num} {vegetable}')`, then obviously you'd need to know the gender of your variable first and would need to transport that as metadata somehow to be able to do proper inflections at all. At that point, it becomes a lot of custom development either way.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`django.contrib.humanize.ordinal`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/humanize/#ordinal). It respects [format localization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/formatting/) as far as I'm aware.

Use it in a template like:

```
{% load humanize %}
{{ item.count|ordinal }} {{ item.name }}
```

Remember to add 'django.contrib.humanize' to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting and set `USE_L10N = True`.

`ordinal` doesn't take into account which word comes after it so this is an imperfect solution, but does at least do *some* localization.

Comment: *"depends on the gender of the word"* — How can `ordinal` account for this…?!

Comment: It doesn't. It's an imperfect solution that answers the first part of the OP's question.